# Spark SQL UDF to run same logic on different tables

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-zeppelin

I want to run the same SQL logic twice, on two different underlying tables. Is there a way to do this in spark that doesn't involve writing the exact same logic twice with just the table name being different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spark.sql(s"query logic from ${tablename}")`.

Other way is using unbound columns via `col("column_name")` instead of referencing them via dataframe reference. And then wrapping this in a function:

```
 def processDf(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("some_col", col("input_col") + lit(5)) 
    // this just an illustration via dummy code
 }
```

Now you can pass any data frame to this function that has input_col in its schema and that is numeric and this would work irrespective of data frame reference. In case of incompatible schemas and advanced use cases I would advise looking into Transformers from spark ml.

It is a common pattern in spark ml for transform method that takes Dataset[_] and outputs DataFrame. In case of incompatible schema you can pass these as parameters.

Comment: Hi, I want to add some complex logic involving joining to another table so I use val tablename="tab1" and then spark.sql(s""" select * from abc join $tablename on 1=1"). This works fine. How do I now pass tablename="tab2" to the same code

Comment: you could wrap this in a function and pass the "tab1" and "tab2" in two separate calls to the function? Or I am not fully getting your problem?